# summing up tier levels in SQL without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL server table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
PlayerID BIGINT NOT NULL
UpdatedAt DATETIME NOT NULL
CurrencyBal MONEY NOT NULL)
```

The table contains 30 records:

```
1,2012-05-10,300
2,2012-05-10,1100
3,2012-05-10,10000
```

I would like to create a query that would return the total number of players, the date the query was run, and a breakdown of Currency Tiers so the output should only be 1 row always that would look like this:

```
Date: 2012-05-10
Total Players: 3
100 - 900 : 1
999 - 1500 : 1
9000 - MAX : 1
```

I know how to total the tier levels with a cursor i am just wondering if there is a way to do this without one. When i try to use a SELECT CASE I am getting 1 row per record. I have tried grouping by UpdatedAt and return the same thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Using solution 1 with the following query:

```
SELECT 
'0 - 10000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 0 AND CreditBalance <= 10000  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
'10001 - 20000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 10001 AND CreditBalance <= 20000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
'20001 - 30000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 20001 AND SUM(CreditBalance) <= 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
'30001 - 60000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 30001 AND SUM(CreditBalance) <= 60000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
'60001 - 100000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 60001 AND SUM(CreditBalance) <= 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
'100001 - 150000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 100001 AND SUM(CreditBalance) <= 150000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
'150001 - 200000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 150001 AND SUM(CreditBalance) <= 200000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
'200001 - 500000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 200001 AND SUM(CreditBalance) <= 500000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
'500001 - 1000000' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 500001 AND SUM(CreditBalance) <= 1000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
'1000001 - Max' = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 1000001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
CONVERT(DATE,LastUpdateDate) AS [Day],
SUM(CreditBalance) AS TotalDailyCurrency, 
COUNT(PlayerID) AS DailyActiveUsers,
AVG(CreditBalance) AS AverageCreditsPerMAU
FROM dbo.PlayerBalances
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,LastUpdateDate) = CONVERT(DATE,GETUTCDATE())
GROUP BY LastUpdateDate
```

and i am getting : Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Your intervals are bad since you might miss users with a balance between the intervals. I.e. `10000.5`. Try using (row1) `<= 10000` and (row2) `> 10000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like all i had to do was remove the ELSE 0 from the case statement. The final solution looks like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 0
                    AND CreditBalance <= 10000 THEN 1
          END) AS '0-10000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 10001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 20000 THEN 1
          END) AS '10001 - 20000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 20001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 30000 THEN 1
          END) AS '20001 - 30000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 30001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 60000 THEN 1
          END) AS '30001 - 60000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 60001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 100000 THEN 1
          END) AS '60001 - 100000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 100001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 150000 THEN 1
          END) AS '100001 - 150000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 150001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 200000 THEN 1
          END) AS '150001 - 200000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 200001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 500000 THEN 1
          END) AS '200001 - 500000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 500001
                    AND CreditBalance <= 1000000 THEN 1
          END) AS '500001 - 1000000' ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CreditBalance >= 1000001 THEN 1
          END) AS '1000001 - MAX'
FROM    dbo.PlayerBalances
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, LastUpdateDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got another alternative and a fiddle for you.  Let me know what you think.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eed70/2

and another alternative for you this might scale better I didn't notice at first how many cases you had.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eed70/4

Comment: The first fiddle returns no results and the second one returns one row for every record. Using the query syntax I have posted above if we eliminate all of the header information want to just pull based on the levels above, can that be done without a cursor. Essentially returning one row for every date with the players broken into tiers. I mean i suppose if not i can always go back to using a cursor but i would rather not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CurrencyBal >= x_1 and CurrencyBal < x_2 THEN 1 ELSE END),
      COUNT(CASE WHEN CurrencyBal >= x_2 and CurrencyBal < x_3 THEN 1 ELSE END)
     ...., 
     UpdatedAt,
     Count(*)
     FROM Table t
     WHERE UpdatedAt = <yourdate>
     GROUP BY UpdatedAt
```

or a better way if you want to define your tiers in a table Tier (min_range,max_range)

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CurrencyBal >= min_range and CurrencyBal < max_range THEN 1 ELSE END),
     min_range,
     UpdatedAt
     FROM Table t INNER JOIN Tier ti ON CurrencyBal >= min_range and CurrencyBal < max_range 
     WHERE UpdatedAt = <yourdate>
     GROUP BY min_range,UpdatedAt
```